# Can a var act like a class method decorated with @property in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

That must be the first time I'm asking something here out of pure curiosity. This is not something I need (at least right now), I merely wonder whether or not it's achievable

Take this code:

```py
class ExponentialDecay:
    def __init__(self):
        self._alpha = 1

    @property
    def alpha(self):
        self._alpha *= .98
        return self._alpha

d = ExponentialDecay()

for i in range(5):
    print(f"{d.alpha=}")
```

it prints:

```
d.alpha=0.98
d.alpha=0.9603999999999999
d.alpha=0.9411919999999999
d.alpha=0.9223681599999999
d.alpha=0.9039207967999998
```

Now, my question is, is there a way to have the exact same behavior, basically without using the dot character.

```py
foo = ... # Some python voodoo
for i in range(5):
    print(f"{foo=}")
```

outputting :

```
foo=0.98
foo=0.9603999999999999
foo=0.9411919999999999
foo=0.9223681599999999
foo=0.9039207967999998
```

**Edit**: I'll insist on the "pure curiosity" motivation by saying: if it is indeed possible, IMHO, don't ever use that in your code, I don't see a situation where I would accept that in a pull request I'm reviewing

Answer (score -1):

Well, you will need something in your loop that would apply the decay to your variable.

Either you have the `foo *= 0.98` in the loop:

```
foo = 1

for i in range(5):
    print("foo=", foo)
    foo *= 0.98
```

Or you can write a helper function and use a global foo variable (which I would not recommend but if this is just a thought exercise, why not ?).

```
foo = 1

def print_and_decay():
    global foo
    print("foo=", foo)
    foo *= 0.98

for i in range(5):
    print_and_decay()
```

Or many other combinations of functions and arguments, but these two are the simplest and worst I could think of, respectively.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear (I'm not most of the time :p). 
My question was: is there a (likely very hacky) mechanism that allows to execute code whenever a var is accessed, 

That could also look like:

```python
>>> foo
'You accessed foo !'
1
```

Comment: Right, I had misunderstood, and if there is a method to modify a variable on access, which I doubt, I do not know it.